# Could not load shared library symbols for linux-vdso.so.1. while debugging

Tags: linux, gdb, glibc

Not loading VDSO.so is one of the famous  bugs you encounter while using gdb and glibc >2.2.
I found that was planned to get repaired in gdb 7.5.1, but it wasn't. 
Okay I found a work-around here [Here](https://sourceware.org/ml/gdb-patches/2012-11/msg00604.html), but I didn't understand it so how to apply it.

OS: Arch Linux 
IDE : QT creator 3.0.82 
Compiler : GCC 4.8.2 
NB: I am not sure if I am breaking the rules including the link above

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> Not loading VDSO.so is one of the famous bugs you encounter while using gdb and glibc >2.2.

No, *it's not*. The problem here is simply a useless warning, which you can safely ignore.

> I found a work-around here Here, but I didn't understand it so how to apply it.

You didn't find a "workaround". You found a patch to GDB, which disables the warning.

To apply it, use the `patch` command, and then build your own GDB. But it is *much* simpler to just ignore the warning in the first place.

Answer (score 6):

For anyone who (like me) just wants gdb to shut up about missing symbols, try adding this to your `~/.gdbinit` (but see caveats below):

```
set logging redirect on
set logging file /dev/null
python
def on_new_objfile(e):
    gdb.execute("set logging off")
    #print "new objfile:",e.new_objfile.filename
    if e.new_objfile.filename[:19] == "system-supplied DSO":
        gdb.execute("set logging on") # hide inevitable error message
gdb.events.new_objfile.connect(on_new_objfile)
end
```

Caveats:

- Monopolizes the `set logging` interface; if you want to use logging you'll need to change it to save the previous logging settings.
- Hard-codes `"system-supplied DSO"`; might be brittle wrt new kernel or gdb versions.
- It assumes at least one objfile will be loaded *after* vdso to reenable output; I'd be very interested if anyone with better gdb internals knowledge could point out the actual after-symbol-load-has-failed hook, since for now it risks leaving output disabled when the program starts if vdso is the last objfile loaded.