# GDB strange behavior - Linux

Tags: c++, linux, debugging, gdb

Yeasterday I made quite big update of my archlinux (after two months). I updated GCC, GDB and QtCreator which I use for development.

```
gcc -v
gcc version 4.9.1 (GCC) 

gdb -v
GNU gdb (GDB) 7.8

qtcreator -version
Qt Creator 3.2.0 based on Qt 5.3.1
```

Today I noticed strange behavior of gdb. If I launch debugger for first time (after fresh restart of computer), it works. But after debugger is stopped, or just debugged application is stopped, It won't run again...and if I start debugging again, it is extremely slow (but CPU shows normal load), it takes minutes to start debugged application again. After while debugging is completely frozen and it has to be killed through "killall gdb".

Only output I get from GDB is:

```
"warning: GDB: Failed to set controlling terminal: Inappropriate ioctl for device\n"
Could not load shared library symbols for linux-vdso.so.1.
Do you need "set solib-search-path" or "set sysroot"?
```

I tried to search here, but this post [Could not load shared library symbols for linux-vdso.so.1. while debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22822425/could-not-load-shared-library-symbols-for-linux-vdso-so-1-while-debugging) tells that "could not load shared library..." is nothing special.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am too using archlinux.

```
gdb -v
GNU gdb (GDB) 7.8

qtcreator -version
Qt Creator 3.2.0 based on Qt 5.3.1`
```

Faced this behavior and solved the problem downgrading gdb to version 7.7

And yes the gdb warining you mention has nothing to do with the issue at hand.

But did not find why does this happen.

Comment: Fixed after upgrade, it was probably bug in GDB